# Ubuntu 14.04 - sound not working, "Dummy Output"

Tags: sound, 14.10

Today, I discovered the sound of my laptop (Acer Aspire E1 532) not working anymore.

The sound settings say "Dummy Output", and

```
sudo aplay -l
```

returns

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

I have applied all the hints given [here](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/).

Is there another hint?

Comment: This is a bug. Functionality that worked before should not break with an update. Please file bugs as bugs. See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/88802)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that somebody has solved that sound problem by "rolling back" the kernel version.

I used

```
uname -r
```

giving me the kernel version. I removed that kernel version with:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic
```

During the removal, I saw that a new DKMS sound driver was being installed. After rebooting, the sound worked! And

```
uname -r
```

now gives me

```
3.13.0-45-generic
```

as the kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

I had to roll back the kernel as well:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
```

now I have this kernel version

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-30-generic
```

I have tried everything I could find in Internet; nothing helped, only the previous kernel

Comment: If you agree with an answer to a specific question, it's customary to upvote that answer rather than duplicate it in a "me too" fashion. WE have no shortage of unanswered questions that could use your assistance. Please see http://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a bug in lanchpad for these issues, so we can debug further?  A bug can be opened by running the following from a terminal:

ubuntu-bug linux

Answer (score 0):

My laptop (a Dell Inspiron), no longer recognized the laptop speakers.

I reloaded the kernel using

sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

Went back to the standard sound control and found the access to the laptop speakers had been restored.